# Schema Markup: Nesting lots of elements, but i can't figure out the proper order to fit them

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, semantic-markup

After testing, all elements I desire are currently in the following JSON. However, according to the schema markup tester, 'suborganization' and 'parentorganization' cannot be nested under 'webSite' Schema. Likewise, the SearchAction feature and 'inLanguage' also needs WebSite markup.

Theoretically I could start the schema with Organization and then identify 'WebSite' with each thing nested in the correct place. Anyone be able to quickly copy+paste things into the correct order to get it recognized? I've struggled to get everything recognized.

Info: ChevronWithTechron owns the brand ChevronExtramile. Then 'ExtaraMile Extras' is a sub-site of ChevronExtraMile

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/",
      "url": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/",
      "name": "Chevron ExtraMile",
      "alternateName": "Chevron ExtraMile Convenience Stores, Rewards & Gas Stations",
      "isPartOf": {
        "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#website"
      },
      "primaryImageOfPage": {
        "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#primaryimage"
      },
      "image": {
        "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#primaryimage"
      },
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/content/uploads/2021/05/extramile-storefront.jpg",
      "datePublished": "2021-01-15T05:53:47+00:00",
      "dateModified": "2023-02-31T15:57:32+00:00",
      "description": "Earn freebies with our huge selection of snacks, coffee, and food at your convenience. Or find information on stores, stations, and deals!",
      "breadcrumb": {
        "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#breadcrumb"
      },
      "inLanguage": "en-US",
      "potentialAction": [
        {
          "@type": "ReadAction",
          "target": [
            "https://www.chevronextramile.com/"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "inLanguage": "en-US",
      "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#primaryimage",
      "url": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/content/uploads/2021/05/extramile-storefront.jpg",
      "contentUrl": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/content/uploads/2021/05/extramile-storefront.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 853,
      "caption": "ExtraMile Storefront"
    },
    {
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#breadcrumb",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "Home"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "@id": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/#website",
      "url": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/",
      "name": "ExtraMile",
      "description": "Look through our assortment of snacks, coffee, or food at your convenience. Get information on stores, stations, deals, rewards programs and more!",
      "sameAs": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/ExtraMileExtras",
        "https://www.instagram.com/chevronextramile/",
        "https://extramileextras.com/"
      ],
      "parentOrganization": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Chevron with Techron",
        "url": "https://www.chevronwithtechron.com/",
        "logo": "https://www.chevronwithtechron.com/content/dam/external/chevron/en_us/marketing-support/web-images/chevron-with-techron/logo.svg"
      },
      "subOrganization": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "ExtraMile Extras",
        "url": "https://extramileextras.com/"
      },
      "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": {
          "@type": "EntryPoint",
          "urlTemplate": "https://www.chevronextramile.com/?s={search_term_string}"
        },
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }],
      "inLanguage": "en-US"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If the content of that link is what you're trying to paste, then it's likely forbidding it because it's inside `<script>` tags.  They might be trying to prevent code execution.

Comment: I think there's some context you have about this data and any possible schema that you might be using or the application this is for.  Can you please add more information?  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not validating because `subOrganization` and `parentOrganization` aren't properties of the [WebSite schema](https://schema.org/WebSite). A website isn't an organization. But an organization *can* be the [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) of a website:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "My Company",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "My Company, Inc.",
    "parentOrganization": ...,
    "subOrganization": ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 
Would the 'mainEntity' signify that the point of the WebSite is to describe the 'organization' though? If so, I worry that it would signify the wrong context to crawlers.
I put together another form using the 'publisher' and then listing out Organizations under that. 
On another site, I did something similar to what you have, but had WebPage as the starter, then WebSite under that so I could use the SearchAction field.

Comment: Yeah, it would signify the website is about the organization which is what I thought your use-case was. Publisher seems to be appropriate

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding correctly what the 'about' Organization would signify? It's a convenience store website (go ahead and visit https://www.chevronextramile.com) 

Basically intended to promote that brand and display products/info. 
In your mind do you think 'organization' would be appropriate?

Comment: I was affirming that `about` wouldn't be appropriate in this case. Your choice of `publisher` seems right